# Modify part of the list and then return the updated list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am playing with Java 8 and trying to work with stream(). What I want to achieve is say, I have a list `[1,2,3,4]`, I want to double the even numbers `2` and `4` and then return the list with the updated values. So, I will get `[1,4,3,8]` as a result. I tried the following but it only returned `[4,8]`.

```
List<Integer> myList =
            Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);

    myList = myList
    .stream()
    .filter(n -> n%2==0)
    .map(n -> n*2)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(myList);
```

Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: You're unnecessarily filtering the list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `filter` method removes those elements that don't fit the condition.  It does not make the rest of the operations not applicable.  Move the condition inside your `map` method.

```
myList = myList
   .stream()
   .map(n -> (n % 2 == 0) ? n*2 : n)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: So, if I have multiple conditions I have to put everything inside the map()? Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Yes.  The purpose of `map` is to change one value into another, as opposed to `filter`, whose purpose is to remove elements that don't fit a condition. To me, this seems elegant enough.

Comment: @xcoder - you can (should) use a method reference for more complex operations. myList.stream().map(this::conditionallyMapSomeElements).collect(Collectors.toList());